# API to hot-restart (not hot-reload) the Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to control a Flutter app (running in dev mode), to make it hot-restart. Thus, I wonder how to implement it? What is the API call to, maybe, vmservice?

P.S. I see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/runtime/vm/service/service.md#reloadsources but it seems to be for hot-reload, not hot-restart.

Comment: Why?  That's generally done by the debugger?>

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I do not quite understand the comment...

Comment: Apropos, beecause I don't understand your question either. :)  You haven't said the problem you're trying to solve yet.  Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution: Just follow devtools's source code and see how its hot-restart is implemented.